# Replacing an array by its length in nested JSON object using .map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to replace an array of objects by the length of this array. 
My data structure looks like this:

```
[
  { 
    date: "2019-11-04", 
    transactionTypes: [
      type1: [
        {irrelevantObject1},
        {irrelevantObject2},
        {irrelevantObject3},
        {irrelevantObject4}
        ],
      type2: [
        {irrelevantObject1},
        {irrelevantObject2},
        {irrelevantObject3}
        ],
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

My goal is to replace the array for each type by the length of the array:

```
 [
  { 
    date: "2019-11-04", 
    transactionTypes: [
      type1: 4,
      type2: 3,
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried various combinations of accessing the Keys via Object.keys() and then mapping etc. but I simply cannot figure it out.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.  Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, but we're happy to help you get your solution working.

Comment: Your object is not valid. `transactionTypes` is either an object or a list.

Comment: @Seblor Ah, yes. Thank you for pointing that out. 
I made a major mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop through the array of data and map the `Object.entries` of `transactionTypes` to have the lengths of its arrays :

```js
const data = [
  {
    date: "2019-11-04",
    transactionTypes: {
      type1: [
        { irrelevantObject1: "irrelevantObject1" },
        { irrelevantObject2: "irrelevantObject2" },
        { irrelevantObject3: "irrelevantObject3" },
        { irrelevantObject4: "irrelevantObject4" }
      ],
      type2: [
        { irrelevantObject1: "irrelevantObject1" },
        { irrelevantObject2: "irrelevantObject2" },
        { irrelevantObject3: "irrelevantObject3" }
      ]
    }
  }
];

const result = data.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  transactionTypes: Object.entries(o.transactionTypes).map(([k, arr]) => ({
    [k]: arr.length
  }))
}));

console.log(result);
```